# Ajax Unique user name search fails JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to create simple unique username check following this tutorial.

http://javaandj2eetutor.blogspot.com/2013/12/check-username-availability-using-java.html

But My ajax call for username is fails. I'm new to ajax and somewhat new for jsp.

Here is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Username Availability</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".username").change(function () {
            var username = $(this).val();
            if (username.length >= 3) {
                $(".status").html("<font color=gray> Checking availability...</font>");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "CheckAvalability",
                    data: "uname="+ username,
                    success: function (msg) {

                        $(".status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                            $(".status").html(msg);

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else {

                $(".status").html("<font color=red>Username should be <b>3</b> character long.</font>");
            }

        });
    });
</script>   
<div>
    <label class="flable">User Name :</label> <input class="username" type="text" name="username"> <span class="status"></span>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Servlet

```
package hsenid;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CheckAvailability extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CheckAvailability.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -734503860925086969L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            logger.info("Check availability called");
            DBConnector dbPool = (DBConnector)getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
            Connection myConn = dbPool.getConn();

            String uname = request.getParameter("username");

            PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement("select username from userdetails where username=?");
            ps.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (!rs.next()) {
                out.println("<font color=green><b>"+uname+"</b> is avaliable</font>");
                logger.info("Username detected!!!");
            }
            else{
                out.println("<font color=red><b>"+uname+"</b> is already in use</font>");
            }
            out.println();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println("Error ->" + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here is my servlet mapping in web.xml.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CheckAvailability</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hsenid.CheckAvailability</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CheckAvailability</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CheckAvailability</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This detects if minimum characters aren't added and also gives the massage check availability when type in there so I think jquery is added. Also I've run the servlet in Eclipse Mars. It do check the if a username is in the table or not. So I believe that the problem calling to the servlet because I can't see the log4j console output then. I'm unable find what wrong with my code. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what output are you getting ?  Is the String trimmed of white space?

Comment: "Checking Availability" message along the input

Comment: url: "CheckAvalability", is not what you have mapped in web.xml

Comment: How should it mapped?
I added the url as we call the servlet. I'm new with ajax.